# Kendo grid: Format dynamically generated column

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

i stuck in kendo grid which getting generated dynamically.
i am generating kendo grid with columns defined dynamically. now what i want is i want to format those column according to there type.
i am using kendo grid with angular js.

```
 $scope.GridModel.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
                read: {
                    url:My Service URL
                    }
            },
    schema: {
             data: function (data) {
             //Here Based on received data in "data" i want to format column.

                }       
            }
 })
```

please suggest what to do.

Comment: It's a bit hard to help since we have no clue of what will be the received data.

Comment: You can address formatting of the grid on `databound`.

Comment: @whipdancer, how to do that? can you please give more details?

Comment: What does code for initializing your grid look like?